# Cannot create spring beans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have spring application and have defined the Clock bean in my SpringMvcConfig.java as follows

```
@Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    }
```

I am using it in my service

```
 @Service
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class DeliveryEstimationService {
    
      @NonNull
      private final SalesChannelService salesChannelService;
      @NonNull
      private final MessageSource messageSource;
      @NonNull
      private final Clock clock;

  public List<LocalDateTime> applyCutoffHoursToLocalDate(List<Integer> cutoffWindowHourList, int plusDays) {
    return cutoffWindowHourList.stream().map(cutoffWindowHour -> LocalDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.now(clock), LocalTime.of(cutoffWindowHour, 0)).plusDays(plusDays))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }}
```

And I see this error
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
... 83 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryEstimationService' defined in file [/home/runner/work/checkout-service/checkout-service/target/classes/com/checkout/delivery/DeliveryEstimationService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.time.Clock' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)

Can someone tell me why spring app cannot create the bean?

I had to use clock because I need to set fixed time for testing purpose

```
void getFixedClock(LocalDate date) {
    fixedClock = Clock.fixed(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    doReturn(fixedClock.instant()).when(clock).instant();
    doReturn(fixedClock.getZone()).when(clock).getZone();
  }
```

Comment: You need to add a `Clock` as a bean to the context, Spring will not automagically create beans for you.

Comment: It is added here in the Spring Config class @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    }

Comment: Well apparently that config isn't used in your test else it would be able to autowire it.

Comment: I have to agree with @M.Deinum . It should work if your config is correct.